# Objective-C method_exchangeImplementations result is not as expected

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm learning Objective-C runtime, and try to use `method_exchangeImplementations` to exchange `addObject:` method and `removeObject:` method of `NSMutableArray`.

My code like this:

```objectivec
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Method removeMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSMutableArray.class, @selector(removeObject:));
        Method addMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSMutableArray.class, @selector(addObject:));
        method_exchangeImplementations(addMethod, removeMethod);
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        [array removeObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)array.count); // expect print 1, actual print 1
        [array addObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)array.count); // expect print 0, actual print 2
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect exchange add/remove function, but seems like only `removeObject:` has been exchange to `addObject:` , `addObject:` still is addObject to array, now I have two addObject method of `NSMutableArray`

I'm not sure the reason. I try to exchange other method like `uppercaseString/lowercaseString` of `NSString`, that work correct.

Comment: Hint: What is the class of `array` at runtime? See [Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved problem. Thanks @Willeke for the tip.

The real class of my array is not `NSMutableArray`, so use `NSMutableArray.class` in `class_getInstanceMethod` can't get correct method. Use `[array class]` is the answer.

```objectivec
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        Method removeMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([array class], @selector(removeObject:));
        Method addMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([array class], @selector(addObject:));
        method_exchangeImplementations(addMethod, removeMethod);
        NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        [array removeObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)array.count); // expect print 1, actual print 1
        [array addObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)array.count); // expect print 0, actual print 0
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's still inconclusive at best. The underlying implementation in the class cluster `NSMutableArray` is prone to change when the number of elements will change. To get a consistent guaranteed behavior you should probably consider an NSArray category with a method name different to `addMethod:` & `removeMethod:` but still indicative of what they actually would do.